# UIScrollview remove space between hidden field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I used `segmentControl` in `UIScrollview`. But my question is that user press first segment control all three field is shown on view.(By default). When user press second segment control  three field should hide and remove between this space. Is it possible? Because in my view total 10 field is their.  I want to hide 3,7,9 field.

Here is my segment control code.

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *s = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

    if (s.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        [txtEmail setHidden:NO];
        [sendInvite setHidden:NO];
        [switchSendInvite setHidden:NO];
        [allowComments setHidden:NO];
        [switchAllow setHidden:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [txtEmail setHidden:YES];
        [sendInvite setHidden:YES];
        [switchSendInvite setHidden:YES];
        [allowComments setHidden:YES];
        [switchAllow setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you need ??

Comment: When i press invite button then invite email other two field display ... that field is hide by first non invite button..

Comment: for that you have to manage manually.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible directly whatever you are thinking, if you want to do like this you must change the frames of all the textfiled and relative objects in that scrollview.

Comment: all textfield place in scrollview.

Comment: the you must change the frames for textfileds every time.

Comment: take one method and change the frames of all the textfields whatever you want to change .